# RoR, Calling column names from a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Ruby on Rails. and I have a module called PatientFactory and it will be included in a Patient model.

I need to access a Patient's id, from this module.

```
module PatientFactory

  def self.included(base)

    # need to access instance variable here
    ...

  end
end
```

But more importantly, I need it in the self.included(base)
I can easily access it outside of this method but how do I access it inside?

Answer (score 2):

Given you want to do this:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PatientFactory
end
```

then you would access the id like this:

```
module PatientFactory
  def get_patient_id
    self.id 
  end
end

a = Patient.new
a.id #=> nil
a.save
a.id #=> Integer
```

when your module gets included it a class, all of its methods become instance methods of that class. if you rather extend them, they get inserted in your class's singleton class, therefore they'll be accessible as if they were class methods.

Comment: Sorry this is not what I need. It needs to be in that method. And no self.id does not work

Comment: you know, self.included is called in the class. base is the class. You have 0 access to any instance there. Can you explain me more throughly what you are achieving?

Comment: Yes, that's why the solution is not that simple.

Comment: "I'm using Ruby on Rails. and I have a module called PatientFactory and it will be included in a Patient model." If you include it in the Model, and being model a class, how do you want to have access to id's from instances which do not exist? Can you just describe what you want to achieve so people can understand?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PatientFactory
end
```

Then you can access the instance as if they were part of Patient's methods.

If you still need to preserve your workflow as you mentioned, Yehuda might offer some help;

http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/12/better-ruby-idioms/

Comment: Sorry, I need it inside the def self.included(base) method and if I call self.id it will not work, because it accessing the class and not the instance. Need some kind of hook.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Well, inside the included(base). There is a workflow that only works like this.